# Outdoor versus indoor amourphous silicon solar cells

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, energy-harvesting

I've read in a few articles that amorphous silicon (a-Si) based solar cells have a greater spectral response for indoor light conditions [here](https://www.electronicproducts.com/Power_Products/Invertors/Bringing_PV_indoors_again.aspx). If this is the case, then why manufacturers emphasize that their a-Si cells are for outdoor conditions and not for indoor or vice versa? It is of course understandable that in indoor you get less voltage and/or current.

My second question, according to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26594/difference-between-indoor-and-outdoor-pv-panels), protection and durability are the main difference between outdoor and indoor cells. If that's the case, then wouldn't it be more reasonable to go for outdoor cells if the final product is being used indoor AND outdoor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) on your first question, it is mostly because the market for outdoor is much bigger than for indoor

2) on the second one, if you design goes outdoor since it has much more stringent conditions it would make a lot of sense to choose an outdoor cell (and also packaging for your electronics would need to adhere to those constraints)